# Smooth transition for sticky navigation on fade in and out

Tags: reactjs, sass, navigation, css-transitions, fade

I am building a react project. it has a sticky navigation on scrolling down. I have managed to get a smooth transition when the sticky navigation appears, but when scrolling back to the top it just pops back in without any transition.
demo here: https://techhype.netlify.app/

I want the sticky nav to transition back into the top in a smooth natural way. how can i achieve this? here is my nav code:

navigation.jsx:

```html
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { content } from "constants/content";
import { UilUserCircle, UilShoppingBag } from "@iconscout/react-unicons";
import Logo from "logo/logo.png";
import LogoNoText from "logo/logo-no-text.png";
import LanguageSelector from "components/LanguageSelector";
import { LangContext } from "utils/LangContext";
import { TabletAndDesktop } from "components/ScreenViewSize";
import "@animated-burgers/burger-rotate/dist/styles.css";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";

function debounce(func, delay) {
  let timeoutId;
  return function (...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

function Navigation() {
  const [lang] = useContext(LangContext);
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isClosing, setIsClosing] = useState(false);
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [isScrolled, setIsScrolled] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();

  const toggleMobileMenu = () => {
    setMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    setIsClosing(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMobileMenuOpen(false);
      setIsClosing(false);
    }, 600); // Adjust the delay to match the slide-up animation duration
  };

  const handleResize = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = debounce(() => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const scrollThreshold = 12; // Adjust this value as needed

      if (scrollPosition < 1) {
        window.location.hash = "";
      }

      setIsScrolled(scrollPosition > scrollThreshold);
    }, 20); // Adjust the debounce delay as needed

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={`nav-container${isScrolled ? " sticky " : " "}`}>
      <div className="navigation container-inner">
        <Link to="/">
          <img
            src={isScrolled ? LogoNoText : Logo}
            className={`logo ${isScrolled ? "logo-hover" : ""}`}
            alt="Techhype Logo"
          />
        </Link>
        <TabletAndDesktop>
          <LanguageSelector />
        </TabletAndDesktop>
        <div
          className={`mobile-menu ${isMobileMenuOpen ? "open" : ""} ${
            isClosing ? "close" : ""
          }`}
        >
          <LanguageSelector />
          <div className="close-button" onClick={closeMenu}>
            <span>&times;</span>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <Link
              to="/shop"
              className={location.pathname === "/shop" ? "active" : ""}
            >
              {content[lang]["menuItem1"]}
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/#howItWorks"
              className={
                location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#howItWorks"
                  ? "active"
                  : ""
              }
              onClick={() => {
                closeMenu();
              }}
            >
              {content[lang]["menuItem2"]}
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/#reviews"
              className={
                location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#reviews"
                  ? "active"
                  : ""
              }
              onClick={() => {
                closeMenu();
              }}
            >
              {content[lang]["menuItem3"]}
            </Link>
            <Link
              to="/contact"
              className={location.pathname === "/contact" ? "active" : ""}
            >
              {content[lang]["menuItem4"]}
            </Link>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <nav className="desktop-menu">
          <Link
            to="/shop"
            className={location.pathname === "/shop" ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {content[lang]["menuItem1"]}
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/#howItWorks"
            className={
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#howItWorks"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }
          >
            {content[lang]["menuItem2"]}
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/#reviews"
            className={
              location.pathname === "/" && location.hash === "#reviews"
                ? "active"
                : ""
            }
          >
            {content[lang]["menuItem3"]}
          </Link>
          <Link
            to="/contact"
            className={location.pathname === "/contact" ? "active" : ""}
          >
            {content[lang]["menuItem4"]}
          </Link>
        </nav>
        <div className="nav-icons">
          <Tooltip title="Login">
            <Link to="/login">
              {windowWidth <= 900 ? (
                <UilUserCircle size={28} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <UilUserCircle size={38} color="white" />
              )}
            </Link>
          </Tooltip>
          <Tooltip title="Cart">
            <Link to="/cart">
              {windowWidth <= 900 ? (
                <UilShoppingBag size={28} color="white" />
              ) : (
                <UilShoppingBag size={38} color="white" />
              )}
            </Link>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
        <div className="burger-menu" onClick={toggleMobileMenu}>
          <div className="burger burger-rotate">
            <div className="burger-lines"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Navigation.scss:

```html
.black-background-container {
  background-color: $color-darker;
}

.nav-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: $color-darker;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;

  a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }

  svg {
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
  }
}

.nav-container.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: $color-dark;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;

  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    animation: fadeDownDesktop 0.6s ease forwards;
  }

  @media (max-width: 899px) {
    animation: fadeDownMobile 0.6s ease forwards;

    .navigation {
      padding: 0.6em 1.5em !important;
    }

    .nav-icons {
      gap: 2em;

      svg {
        width: 22px;
        height: 22px;
      }
    }
  }

  .navigation {
    padding: 1em;
  }

  .burger {
    font-size: 8px !important;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 30px;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: center;

    &:hover {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
      filter: brightness(1);
    }
  }

  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    .language-selector {
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -10;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes fadeDownDesktop {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 123px;
    background-color: $color-darker;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 62px;
    background-color: $color-dark;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}


@keyframes fadeDownMobile {
  from {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 76px;
    background-color: $color-darker;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 49.19px;
    background-color: $color-dark;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2em 1em 1em 1em;
  position: relative;

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    padding: 1em 1em 0 1em;
  }

  .desktop-menu {
    display: flex;
    gap: 60px;

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;

      &.active {
        &::after {
          width: 100%;
          right: auto;
          left: 0;
        }
      }

      &::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0; /* Updated: Set the right position instead of left */
        width: 0%;
        height: 2px;
        background-color: $color-hover;
        transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.85, 0.32, 1.2);
      }

      &:hover {
        &::after {
          width: 100%;
          right: auto; /* Updated: Reset the right position on hover */
          left: 0; /* Added: Set the left position on hover */
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .burger-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  .nav-icons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1.5em;

    svg:hover {
      transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
      fill: $color-hover;
    }
  }

  .mobile-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: $color-dark;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 100;

    &.open {
      animation: slideDown 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
      display: flex;
    }

    &.close {
      animation: slideUp 0.6s ease-in-out forwards;
    }

    nav {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      gap: 20px;
      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;

        &.active {
          &::after {
            width: 100%;
            right: auto;
            left: 0;
          }
        }

        &::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 0; /* Updated: Set the right position instead of left */
          width: 0%;
          height: 2px;
          background-color: $color-hover;
          transition: width 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.85, 0.32, 1.2);
        }

        &:hover {
          color: $color-hover;
        }
      }
    }

    .close-button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.6em;
      right: 0.8em;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: white;
      font-size: 38px;
      font-weight: bold;

      &:hover {
        color: $color-hover;
      }
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 900px) {
    .desktop-menu {
      display: none;
    }

    .burger-menu {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      align-items: center;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;

      .burger {
        font-size: 10px;
      }

      &:hover .burger-lines,
      &:hover .burger-lines:after,
      &:hover .burger-lines:before {
        background-color: $color-hover;
      }
    }
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 75px;
  transition: filter 0.3s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.9);
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    width: 60px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    width: 60px;
  }
}

.language-selector {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0.5em;

  label {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;

    &:focus {
      color: $color-primary;
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    left: 1.5em;
    top: 2em;
    right: auto;
  }
}

//Animations for the mobile menu
@keyframes slideDown {
  from {
    top: -100vh;
  }
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    top: 0;
  }
  to {
    top: -100vh;
  }
}
```